# Remove duplicate from xdocument based on element value

Tags: c#

I have a string as below

```
<RuleGeneratorContextMenuXML>
   <Contains>Principal Amount</Contains>
   <NotContains />
   <Contains>Principal Amount</Contains>
   <NotContains />
   <Contains>Interest Payment Date</Contains>
   <NotContains />
   <Contains />
   <NotContains>Interest Payment Date</NotContains>
   <Contains />
   <NotContains>Interest Payment Date</NotContains>
   <Contains />
   <NotContains>Maturity falls</NotContains>
</RuleGeneratorContextMenuXML>
```

i used xDocument to parse it like

string keywords = "

```
<RuleGeneratorContextMenuXML>
   <Contains>Principal Amount</Contains>
   <NotContains />
   <Contains>Principal Amount</Contains>
   <NotContains />
   <Contains>Interest Payment Date</Contains>
   <NotContains />
   <Contains />
   <NotContains>Interest Payment Date</NotContains>
   <Contains />
   <NotContains>Interest Payment Date</NotContains>
   <Contains />
   <NotContains>Maturity falls</NotContains>
</RuleGeneratorContextMenuXML>
```

"

var x Doc = xDocument.Parse.Parse(Keywords);

From the x Doc i want to remove duplicate elements based on the values. so my result x Doc should be as

```
<RuleGeneratorContextMenuXML>
   <Keywords>
      <Contains>Principal Amount</Contains>
      <Contains>Interest Payment Date</Contains>
      <NotContains>Interest Payment Date</NotContains>
      <NotContains>Maturity falls</NotContains>
   </Keywords>
</RuleGeneratorContextMenuXML>
```

This is what i tried so far

```
    for each (var node in xDoc. Descendants().Where(x => "Contains NotContains"                  .Contains(x.Name.Local Name)))
    {
        if (node.Value == "")
        {
            node.Remove();
        }
    }
```

But this did not achieve what I exactly want. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: var duplicates = (from req in xDoc.Descendants("Keywords")
                              group req by req.Descendants( "Contains").First().Value
                                  into g
                                  where g.Count() > 1
                                  select g.Skip(1)).SelectMany(elements => elements);
            foreach (var duplicate in duplicates)
            {
                duplicate.Remove();
            }

Comment: Even tried with this also. But no result

Comment: Your boolean expression makes simply no sense. I'm not common with xml, but why don't you simply filter your collection by filtering the nodes with matching values?

Comment: Removed thanks and reformated

Answer (score 0):

Your code in the comments is close.  You need to group the elements of a specific name by value, then either remove all in the case they are empty or remove all but the first in the case they have a value:

```
doc.Descendants("Contains")
    .GroupBy(x => x.Value)            
    .SelectMany(x => x.Key == string.Empty ? x : x.Skip(1))
    .Remove();
```

You can implement `NotContains` the same way, or ideally refactor to remove the duplication.

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7nyqzm) for a demo.

Comment: Great. Thats exactly what i wanted. Thanks alot Charles